# DataSource load method not working with ngrx store

Tags: datagrid, devexpress, ngrx, angular7, devextreme-angular

How to use DataSource load method with ngrx store?

I have these problems:
 1. When the page loads, the load method is called
 2. Infinite loading
 3. 2 requests are send to server instead of 1

If I use the service directly then there will be no problems.

**TypeScript:**

```
this.ds = new CustomStore({
  load: (loadOptions: any) => {
    this.myFacade.loadAllRecords(this.filter, loadOptions);
    return this.myFacade.records$
      .toPromise()
      .then(result => {
        return result;
      });
  }
});
```

[image: Infinite loading]

```
this.ds = new CustomStore({
  load: (loadOptions: any) => {
    this.myFacade.loadAllRecords(this.filter, loadOptions);
    return new Promise(resolve => this.myFacade.records$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(resolve)).then(result => {
        return result;
      });
  }
});
```

[image: First Loading]
  [image: Run command - this.dataGrid.instance.refresh() - 2 requests are send to server instead of 1]

```
export class MyFacade {
  public records$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.records$ =
      this.store.pipe(select(myQuery.getRecords));
  }
  loadAllRecords(model: myModel, loadOptions?: LoadOptions) {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadRecords(model, loadOptions));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your Observable `records$` is not finished. And the `toPromise()` is still waiting for resolving of the Observable.

I would do the following:

in the facade add `take(1)`:

```js
this.records$ =
  this.store.pipe(
    select(myQuery.getRecords),
    take(1)
  );
```

and then change the `CustomStore`:

```js
this.ds = new CustomStore({
  load: (loadOptions: any) => {
    this.myFacade.loadAllRecords(this.filter, loadOptions);
    return this.myFacade.records$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).toPromise();
  }
});
```